# What is a mathematical definition of the Maxwellian spacetime?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, coordinate-systems

While this problem originated in physics, the question is purely mathematical. Because Maxwell's equations were not invariant under the Galilean transformation, Maxwell proposed his version of spacetime. It is as a 4D collection of points, such that:

1. Between any two points $p(t, x, y, z)$ and $q(t', x', y', z')$ there is a definite *temporal interval* $T(p, q) = t' − t$.
2. Between any two *simultaneous* points $p(t, x, y, z)$ and $q(t, x', y', z')$ there is a definite *Euclidean distance*

$$R(p,q) = \sqrt{(x' − x)^2 + (y' − y)^2 + (z' − z)^2}$$

3. Any worldline $\gamma$ through the point $p$ has a definite twist $\Omega(γ, p)$.

As a result of the third condition, *linear* acceleration is not absolute like in the Galilean spacetime. There is not enough structure in
the Maxwellian spacetime to distinguish straight worldlines from curved
worldlines.

However, rotation is still absolute, because the third condition allows telling when a worldline is "twisted". For a worldline $\gamma$ and a point $p$ on $\gamma$, the absolute rotation of $\gamma$ w.r.t. $p$ is given by $\Omega(γ, p)$.

[image]

(Image and partial content credit: [Jonathan Bain, NY University](http://faculty.poly.edu/~jbain/spacetime/lectures/11.Spacetime.pdf).)

Properties of the Maxwellian spacetime:

1. No inertial frames (as opposed to many inertial frames in the Galilean spacetime).
2. Velocity is relative.
3. Acceleration is relative (as opposed to absolute in the Galilean spacetime).
4. Rotation is absolute.
5. Simultaneity is absolute.

The mathematical definition of the Galilean spacetime is a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) $(\mathbb{R}^4,t_{ab},h^{ab},\nabla)$ where $t_{ab}$ (temporal metric) and $h^{ab}$ (spatial metric) are tensor fields and $\nabla$ is the coordinate derivative operator specifying the geodesic trajectories ([Spacetime Structure](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/11265/1/spacetimestructure.pdf)).

A single metric does not work, because the speed of light is infinite, so time and space should be treated separately with the temporal metric:

$$t_{ab}=(\text{d}_a t)(\text{d}_b t)$$

and the spatial metric:

$$h^{ab}=\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^a\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^b+
\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^a\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^b+
\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^a\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^b$$

Finally, $\nabla$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$
is a unique flat derivative operator that for each coordinate $x^i$ satisfies:

$$\nabla_a\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)^b=\mathbf{0}$$

In turn, the Newtonian spacetime is the same tuple with an additional structure $(\mathbb{R}^4,t_{ab},h^{ab},\nabla,\lambda^a)$ where $\lambda^a$ is a field that adds the preferred frame of rest:

$$\lambda^a=\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^a$$

What is a rigorous mathematical definition of the Maxwellian spacetime? Intuitively, it may be the same Galilean tuple, but with some additional structure (or a reduced structure) similar to how the Newtonian spacetime is created by adding $\lambda$ to the Galilean tuple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In writing this question there is really no need to completely lay waste to the widely accepted order of events as recorded and documented by Historians of Science. Maxwell's electromagnetic theory was devised long after Newton's death. The concept of space-time was proposed by Hermann Minkowski in 1907 long after James Clerk Maxwell's death in 1879. What you describe as Newton's Dilemma, was actually something like Einstein's Dilemma. There are other problems with your first paragraph, however you can start with fixing the reference to "Maxwellian Space" [Space-time?] in the question title.

Comment: @JamesArathoon Thank you for the corrections. I am neither a historian nor mathematician, sorry for mixing up the order of events. I will try to fix it today after work.

Comment: @JamesArathoon safesphere's version of the events strikes me as possibly a consequence of habitual white lies given by professors for pedagogical purposes, except taken to an unacceptable extreme in this case.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein No, it's just my ignorance. History is my weak point. I've no idea who lived when. I'll fix it shortly, no worries. Please ignore the mixup, the question is about the Maxwellian spacetime.

Comment: Thanks for rewriting the first part of your question. I don't think it can be easily answered without considering the context. The "Maxwellian Space-time" you are attempting to define, in terms of physics, is very much an action at a distance framework. Maxwell's actual theory of electromagnetism is an action by contact theory with space full of macroscopically well defined scalar and vector potentials (and retarded potentials) without any reference at all to the concept of mass.

Comment: After Lorentz we now add an action at a distance equation to Maxwell's original theory, which introduces the concept of mass "ad-hoc" to electromagnetism. If you accept a solution to this, is that Quantum Field Theory (an action at a distance theory) can be reduced to Maxwell's theory, via the four equations, then you will be prepared to believe that there is no such thing as electric or magnetic fields acting by contact, but only virtual photons acting at a distance. If you can get anything rigorous at all mathematically speaking from this inconsistent mess you would be a miracle worker.

Comment: @JamesArathoon I know :) This for example shows the inconsistency: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93430/how-is-the-classical-em-field-modeled-in-quantum-mechanics  - My question however is not about electromagnetism, but specifically about the structure of the Maxwellian spacetime. I just wonder what "relative acceleration" means mathematically.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Twist"? Is that an angle assigned at every point $p$ along a world line $\gamma$ which acts to rotate the coordinates around the normal to the worldline (or something)? If so, it seems that you are just describing a line bundle over Euclidean space.

Comment: @levitopher I am not sure. This term came from here: http://faculty.poly.edu/~jbain/spacetime/lectures/11.Spacetime.pdf - In addition, I see these papers mentioning the Maxwellian spacetime: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02393 - and: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.00148 - Perhaps one of these references can help with your question.

Comment: Is your question not answered by those papers? On page 8 of 1707.02393 the author gives a formal definition of a Maxwellian spacetime in the same spirit as your Galilean spacetime above. He even goes on to define some special operators which follow, in the same way way you put a $\nabla$ in your tuple. What else do you want in your mathematical definition?

Comment: @levitopher Thanks so much for your answer! I will review it over the weekend and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your definition of a Galilean Spacetime, I will mostly rewrite what is found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02393.pdf. A Maxwellian spacetime is a tuple $(M,t_a,h^{ab},\Omega)$ where $M$ is a smooth manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$, $t_a$ is a temporal metric on $M$, $h^{ab}$ is a spatial metric on $M$, and $\Omega$ is a standard of rotation compatible with $t_a$ and $h^{ab}$. Further, the metric $h^{ab}$ is complete on spatial surfaces $\mathbb{R}^3_t$ foliated by $t:M\to \mathbb{R}$.

For any given $M$, we have a unique spatial derivative operator $D$ which obeys $D_a h^{bc}=0$.

(One change I am making here is not including the derivative in the tuple. It might be linquistics, but if there is a unique derivative $\nabla_a(\partial/\partial_i)^b=0$, we don't need to specify it in our choice of tuple. By picking $M$, we are automatically picking $\nabla$)