# Metric of spacetime with zero speed of light

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

Despite references to physical spaces, this question is purely mathematical on differential geometry.

While deriving coordinate transformations based on common assumptions of homogeneity and uniformity of space and time (see [A Primer on Special Relativity](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath307/kmath307.htm) or [Nothing but Relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0302045)), typically three logical options are considered:

1. Finite speed of light - Minkowski spacetime.
2. Infinite speed of light - Galilean spacetime, ruled out by observation.
3. Imaginary speed of light (negative square) - Euclidean spacetime, ruled out by causality.

There exist however the forth logical option:

4. Zero speed of light.

At first it appears unreal, but in fact there exists a conceptual case asymptotically close to this scenario.

Imagine a thin spherical shell approaching its Schwarzschild radius. Spacetime inside this empty shell is locally flat Minkowski with the same time dilation as at the shell. As the shell approaches an infinite time dilation at the Schwarzschild radius, the speed of light at and inside the shell approaches zero.

What is the metric structure of this space in the limit of the speed of light being exactly zero?

Metrics for other three cases are well known. The Euclidean and Minkowski metrics don't require an introduction. The Galilean structure is described here: [What is a mathematical definition of the Maxwellian spacetime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588492/what-is-a-mathematical-definition-of-the-maxwellian-spacetime)

Would the $c=0$ spacetime collapse simply to a 3D Euclidean space with no time or would it have two separate metrics for space and time like the Galilean spacetime?

Comment: It's a good question, I don't know. 
However, Minkowski metric with $c=0$ is degenerate. This may cause difficulties e.g. with  volume element or different isomorphisms widely used (e.g. this between contravariant and covariant vectors).

Comment: @PawełCzyż If by "degenerate" you mean a zero determinant, then the Minkowski metric $dt^2-\dfrac{dr^2}{c^2}$ is also degenerate with $c=\infty$ (please correct me if I am wrong). However, this is the case of the Galilean spacetime with separate spatial and temporal metrics. Physically though, yes, $c=0$ seems to imply no energy, no matter, no time, no motion, nothing happening ever. Still this space may have some interesting properties. For example, how can it be connected to a pseudo-Riemannian manifold (e.g at the event horizon)?

Comment: "in the limit of the speed of light being exactly zero". does this mean "the speed of light is zero"?

Comment: A physical space that does not transmit transverse waves (physically equivalent to $c=0$) could perhaps be formed as a result as of a phase change e.g. a "solid" like space changing to a "fluid" like space. A physical space which does not transmit light cannot have a metric defined with reference to light. It will be interesting what you conclude in regard to mathematical spaces.

Comment: @mathworker21 I am not sure, this is a part of a question. For example, is $x\cdot\sin{(x)}$ exactly zero at $x=0$? I am not a mathematician, so I am just trying to be careful with my statements. My primary interest is, yes, $c=0$. However, in case this option is trivial or gives a different result, please also consider the following option as well: $$\lim_{t\to\infty}c=0$$ where t is the Schwarzschild coordinate time, e.g. the time of a thin massive shell collapsing to the event horizon, but never exactly reaching it. In this case $c$ is the speed of light asymptotic to zero inside the shell.

Comment: @mathworker21 Apparently the latter spacetime locally is Minkowski with a caveat that the local (proper) time there ends abruptly, which, I assume may be a problem (or at least an issue to resolve), because timelike geodesics cannot be continued passed the moment of proper time that corresponds to the infinite time outside. For example, if at that moment the shell crosses the horizon, then I'd like to know how a transition happens inside from the flat to Schwarzschild geometry (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929400) from the mathematical viewpoint. Thanks so much!

Comment: @JamesArathoon "*A physical space which does not transmit light cannot have a metric defined with reference to light*" - One metric cannot be defined with $c=0$ or $c=\infty$. However, the latter case is the Galilean spacetime where the metric is split in two, spatial and temporal (please see the link in the question). Then $c$ cancels out from both metrics. Whether a similar mathematical structure exists for $c=0$ is exactly the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what would happen with the spherical shell; I'm not proficient with General Relativity. But I guess that nothing would move (or that everything "moves" in the same timelike direction), and I generally agree with [Qiaochu Yuan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3358997/472818).

---

The standard Lorentzian metric $\eta$ applies to a pair of vectors $u,v$ as

$$\eta(u,v)=u^xv^x+u^yv^y+u^zv^z-c^2u^tv^t.$$

Sometimes it's better to think of $\eta$ as a function from vectors to covectors, in which case $\eta(u,v)$ should be written as $\eta(u)(v)$, with

$$\eta(u)=\eta(u^xe_x+u^ye_y+u^ze_z+u^te_t)=u^x\varepsilon^x+u^y\varepsilon^y+u^z\varepsilon^z-c^2u^t\varepsilon^t.$$

$e_\mu$ and $\varepsilon^\nu$ are the basis vectors and covectors, related by $\varepsilon^\nu(e_\mu)=\delta_\mu^\nu$. This form of $\eta$ has an inverse, a function from covectors to vectors:

$$\eta^{-1}(\omega)=\eta^{-1}(\omega_x\varepsilon^x+\omega_y\varepsilon^y+\omega_z\varepsilon^z+\omega_t\varepsilon^t)=\omega_xe_x+\omega_ye_y+\omega_ze_z-\frac{1}{c^2}\omega_te_t.$$

The Galilean metrics come from taking $c\to\infty$ :

$$\eta_\infty^+(u)=\lim_{c\to\infty}\frac{1}{c^2}\eta(u)=-u^t\varepsilon^t$$

$$\eta_\infty^-(\omega)=\lim_{c\to\infty}\eta^{-1}(\omega)=\omega_xe_x+\omega_ye_y+\omega_ze_z.$$

These have signature $(0,0,0,-)$ on vectors, and $(+,+,+,0)$ on covectors. (And the limit has broken their inverse relationship.) Now we look at zero lightspeed:

$$\eta_0^+(u)=\lim_{c\to0}\eta(u)=u^x\varepsilon^x+u^y\varepsilon^y+u^z\varepsilon^z$$

$$\eta_0^-(\omega)=\lim_{c\to0}c^2\eta^{-1}(\omega)=-\omega_te_t.$$

These have signature $(+,+,+,0)$ on vectors, and $(0,0,0,-)$ on covectors. In this sense, $c\to0$ and $c\to\infty$ are dual to each other.

---

Another way to express $\eta$ uses the tensor product:

$$\eta=\eta_{\mu\nu}\varepsilon^\mu\otimes\varepsilon^\nu=\varepsilon^x\otimes\varepsilon^x+\varepsilon^y\otimes\varepsilon^y+\varepsilon^z\otimes\varepsilon^z-c^2\varepsilon^t\otimes\varepsilon^t.$$

You asked in the comments (but not in the OP) about covariant derivatives. Let's require the metric to be "constant", differentiating with respect to $e_\xi$ :

$$0=\partial_\xi\eta=(\partial_\xi\eta_{\mu\nu})\varepsilon^\mu\otimes\varepsilon^\nu+\eta_{\mu\nu}(\partial_\xi\varepsilon^\mu)\otimes\varepsilon^\nu+\eta_{\mu\nu}\varepsilon^\mu\otimes(\partial_\xi\varepsilon^\nu)$$

(each $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is just a number, $1$ or $0$ or $-c^2$)

$$=(0)+\eta_{\mu\nu}(-\Gamma^\mu_{\pi\xi}\varepsilon^\pi)\otimes\varepsilon^\nu+\eta_{\mu\nu}\varepsilon^\mu\otimes(-\Gamma^\nu_{\pi\xi}\varepsilon^\pi)$$

(renaming summation variables in the last term)

$$=-\eta_{\mu\nu}\Gamma^\mu_{\pi\xi}\varepsilon^\pi\otimes\varepsilon^\nu-\eta_{\pi\mu}\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\xi}\varepsilon^\pi\otimes\varepsilon^\nu$$

$$=-\Big(\eta_{\mu\nu}\Gamma^\mu_{\pi\xi}+\eta_{\mu\pi}\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\xi}\Big)\varepsilon^\pi\otimes\varepsilon^\nu.$$

All of the tensors $\varepsilon^x\otimes\varepsilon^x,\;\varepsilon^x\otimes\varepsilon^y,\;\varepsilon^y\otimes\varepsilon^x,\cdots$ are independent, so this sum vanishing means that each coefficient vanishes:

$$0=\eta_{\mu\nu}\Gamma^\mu_{\pi\xi}+\eta_{\mu\pi}\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\xi}$$

(and the sum over $\mu$ reduces to a single term, because most of $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ are $0$)

$$=\eta_{\nu\nu}\Gamma^\nu_{\pi\xi}+\eta_{\pi\pi}\Gamma^\pi_{\nu\xi}.$$

This is to be true for all $\xi,\pi,\nu$. Cycling the names,

$$0=\eta_{\pi\pi}\Gamma^\pi_{\xi\nu}+\eta_{\xi\xi}\Gamma^\xi_{\pi\nu}$$

$$0=\eta_{\xi\xi}\Gamma^\xi_{\nu\pi}+\eta_{\nu\nu}\Gamma^\nu_{\xi\pi}$$

and using $\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\xi}=\Gamma^\nu_{\xi\mu}$ (no torsion), these 3 equations have the form $a=-b=c=-a$ which implies $a=0$, that is,

$$\eta_{\nu\nu}\Gamma^\nu_{\pi\xi}=0.$$

Finally, with the Lorentzian metric (finite $c$), each $\eta_{\nu\nu}\neq0$, and thus all Christoffel symbols must vanish: $\Gamma^\nu_{\pi\xi}=0$. This means that the "straight lines" are the obvious ones.

---

Applying the same process to $\eta^{-1}$ instead, we would get

$$0=\eta^{\nu\nu}\Gamma^\pi_{\nu\xi}+\eta^{\pi\pi}\Gamma^\nu_{\pi\xi}$$

but we'd need to multiply by $\eta^{\xi\xi}$ (losing information in the non-Lorentzian cases) to combine the 3 cycled equations. The result is

$$\eta^{\nu\nu}\eta^{\xi\xi}\Gamma^\pi_{\nu\xi}=0$$

which, with the Lorentzian metric, again gives $\Gamma^\pi_{\nu\xi}=0$.

---

For the Galilean metrics, making $\eta_\infty^+$ constant gives only $\Gamma^t_{\pi\xi}=0$.

Making $\eta_\infty^-$ constant gives $\Gamma^\pi_{\nu\xi}=0$ for the spatial coordinates $\{\xi,\pi,\nu\}\subseteq\{x,y,z\}$, and $\Gamma^x_{xt}=\Gamma^y_{yt}=\Gamma^z_{zt}=\big(\Gamma^x_{yt}+\Gamma^y_{xt}\big)=\big(\Gamma^x_{zt}+\Gamma^z_{xt}\big)=\big(\Gamma^y_{zt}+\Gamma^z_{yt}\big)=0$.

There's still some freedom; for example $\Gamma^x_{tt}\neq0$, which says that a timelike geodesic may accelerate in the $x$ direction. Even if all other Christoffel symbols vanish, one component of the Riemann curvature is $R^x_{txt}=\partial_x\Gamma^x_{tt}$ which is not necessarily zero. (It is zero if $\Gamma^x_{tt}$ is uniform across space, which would happen if the Galilean spacetime is deformed in the sense of [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle), sliding the spacelike layers over each other while maintaining each layer's shape; this is equivalent to using an accelerating reference frame.) See also Schuller's lecture "[Newtonian spacetime is curved](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBlCu1zgD4Y&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_&index=9)".

---

For zero-lightspeed, making $\eta_0^+$ constant gives $\Gamma^x_{\pi\xi}=\Gamma^y_{\pi\xi}=\Gamma^z_{\pi\xi}=0$.

Making $\eta_0^-$ constant gives $\Gamma^t_{t\xi}=\Gamma^x_{t\xi}=\Gamma^y_{t\xi}=\Gamma^z_{t\xi}=0$ (but those last three are special cases of the previous line, with $\pi=t$).

Again there's some freedom; for example $\Gamma^t_{xx}\neq0$. Similar comments apply.

Comment: Thank you! A fantastic answer that I plan to accept shortly, although it would take me a bit longer to fully comprehend. Meanwhile, a quick question. I understand I cannot do a coordinate transformation (velocity boost) in this spacetime, because all velocities are zero. However, what if this spacetime is spatially limited, say, to a ball of a certain size with a gradient of the speed of light outside reaching zero at the border? If I look at this ball from outside, I can change to a coordinate system, in which the ball is moving (still with no relative motion inside of course). ... [TBC]

Comment: Intuitively I don't see any contradiction in this setup, but I wonder if there are any caveats or anything to say or clarify about the description of this spacetime when it is looked at from an outside moving frame (where by "looked" I just mean coordinates, but not light rays, as no light can come from there of course)? Thanks again!

Comment: With $c\to\infty$, a velocity boost becomes a shear transformation preserving spacelike directions. With $c\to0$, a velocity boost becomes a shear transformation preserving the timelike direction.  As for the sphere, maybe you could get an answer at https://physics.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 7):

From a mathematical perspective this is a question about [signatures of quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Real_quadratic_forms). On $\mathbb{R}^4$ with space coordinates $(x, y, z)$ and time coordinate $t$ we can consider

1. A Euclidean metric, corresponding to the quadratic form $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (ct)^2$, with signature $(+, +, +, +)$
2. A Lorentzian / Minkowski metric, corresponding to the quadratic form $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - (ct)^2$, with signature $(+, +, +, -)$ (or the  negative of this, depending on your conventions)
3. A Galilean metric ($c \to \infty$), corresponding to the quadratic form $-t^2$, with signature $(0, 0, 0, -)$; we get this by dividing the previous expression by $c^2$ and just taking the limit in the most obvious sense
4. A $c = 0$ metric, corresponding to the quadratic form $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, with signature $(+, +, +, 0)$.

The physical significance of this is not entirely clear to me; I don't have much experience thinking about relativity, but here are some speculations off the top of my head.

If we think of these quadratic forms as describing spacelike vs. timelike vs. lightlike directions, then in Galilean spacetime every direction is timelike or lightlike, while in $c = 0$ spacetime every direction is spacelike or lightlike. I guess we can think of $c$ as describing the "slope of the light cone," in which case the Galilean limit $c \to \infty$ corresponds to everything being in your light cone, while the $c \to 0$ limit corresponds to nothing being in your light cone.

I guess your conception of the Galilean limit $c \to \infty$ is that it describes a universe where "time is infinitely more important than space," so first we have the quadratic form $-t^2$ dividing up time slices but then in each timeslice we have the usual 3d Euclidean metric, reflecting the fact that an infinite speed of light means we can in principle reach any point in space from any other point in space at a given time, but we still can't e.g. travel backwards in time. If so, then the corresponding $c \to 0$ limit describes a universe where "space is infinitely more important than time," so we can think of it as divided up into isolated points of 3d space, each of which has a timeline with a 1d time metric, reflecting the fact that a zero speed of light means nothing can move.

Perhaps we should call the $c = 0$ case [Zenoan spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Paradoxes_of_motion).

**Edit, 9/4/20:** The $c \to 0$ limit is briefly discussed in Freeman Dyson's *[Missed Opportunities](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183533964)*; he calls the corresponding automorphism group $G$ the "Carroll group," after Lewis Carroll:

> "A slow sort of country," said the Queen, "Now, here, you see, it takes
> all the running you can do, to keep in the same place."

Comment: Your description that "*space is infinitely more important than time*" matches my intuition and "*it as divided up into isolated points of 3d space, each of which has a timeline*" confirms my expectation of "two separate metrics for space and time". This is a spacetime with absolute space as opposed to Galilean absolute time. So the two metrics are the same as Galilean, right? And the difference is in the coordinate derivative operator specifying geodesics, as defined in 3.1 here: http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/11265/1/spacetimestructure.pdf - If so, what is the expression for this operator?

Comment: As a side (relativity) note, this spacetime would occupy a (spherical) region inside a thin and heavy collapsing shell (plus some other cases). Being very much finite in its spatial extent, it is important how this spacetime is described from outside. E.g. I can boost my frame to some velocity, so my coordinates now are (x',y',z',t'). So how does my relative space and time reconcile with the absolute space and "infinitely less significant" time inside the shell? Having equations would help with this understanding, so I wonder if you could please check the link in my comment above. Thanks much!

Comment: Also, a related (but less important) question on the connection of this spacetime to infinity outside both having the same spatial scale without an obvious reason: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3352423/how-does-the-iron-shell-know-about-infinity

Comment: @safesphere: I'm not familiar enough with physics or with differential geometry here to be sure I know what I'm talking about here. If I understand correctly, I think a geodesic in Zenoan spacetime is only allowed to move in time and can't move in space. Does that answer your question about the covariant derivative?

Comment: My inquiry is purely mathematical on the mathematical structure of this spacetime. So (1), are the metrics the same a s Galilean? And (2) the expression for the derivative operator. While I understand the intuition for it perfectly well, you with a nearly 300,000 math reputation are equipped to write down this expression a thousand times better than me with a reputation of 300, barely enough to set a bounty on my question :) Even if differential geometry is not your specialty, I hope you could try adding  a comment or edit. I just wouldn't know where to start and if whatever I do is correct :)

Comment: I think a better approach to Galilean spacetime is to put the $000+$ (or $000-$) metric on vectors, and $+\!+\!+0$ on covectors rather than spacelike vectors. (That's implied, but not explained, in the linked "Maxwellian" question, by using upper indices on $h^{ab}$.) For the $c\to0$ spacetime, we could put the $+\!+\!+0$ metric on vectors, and $000+$ on covectors; so $c\to0$ and $c\to\infty$ are dual to each other. I haven't thought about the spherical shell or covariant derivatives.

Comment: Thanks also for citing the beautiful paper of Dyson (which I didn't know about).

Answer (score 1):

Your classification includes 4 cases. Paraphrasing Yoda: "no, there's another". But, first things first.

In the singular cases, the covariant and contravariant metrics are no longer inverses, but separate, as dual metrics.

In general, you may consider a 2-parameter family of geometries that have the following as their invariants:
$$
β dt^2 - α \left(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2\right), \\
β \left(\left(\frac{∂}{∂x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{∂}{∂y}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{∂}{∂z}\right)^2\right) - α \left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right)^2, \\
dt \frac{∂}{∂t} + dx \frac{∂}{∂x} + dy \frac{∂}{∂y} + dz \frac{∂}{∂z},
$$
where $(α,β) ≠ (0,0)$. The first invariant yields a line element for a metric, the second yields a differential operator that embodies the dual metric. The contraction of the metric and its dual yields the third invariant, up to a factor of $-αβ$. For singular metrics, this reduces to 0.

If $αβ > 0$, that yields a geometry possessing $c = \sqrt{β/α}$ as a finite non-zero invariant speed. If $αβ < 0$, then it's the 4-dimensional Euclidean geometry, where time is a spatial dimension - which (according to Hawking and Hartle) is the local geometry of the Universe before the Big Bang; i.e. a 4-dimensional time-less space, instead of a 3+1 dimensional space-time.

If $α = 0$ and $β ≠ 0$, that's the geometry that has Galilean symmetry, while for $α ≠ 0$ and $β = 0$, it is the geometry possessing Carrollean symmetry. The limit case $(α,β) = (0,0)$ is actually also meaningful; this describing the geometry that has the Static Group as its local symmetry group. In that case, however, additional geometric invariants arise.

So, for the Carrollean case, the metric and dual metric are embodied by the first two of these invariants, which - we normalize $α$ to $-1$ - become:
$$dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2, \hspace 1em \left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right)^2.$$

The symmetry group that preserves these two invariants and the third above-mentioned invariant is just the Carroll group.

You can embed these geometries in 5 dimensions, adding an extra coordinate $u$, by treating the line element an expression for $β ds^2$, with an invariant (or "proper") time $s$ decomposed into $s = t + α u$. Then, one has, instead, the following sets of invariants:
$$
dt + α du, \hspace 1em dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 + 2 β dt du + α β du^2, \\
\frac{∂}{∂u}, \hspace 1em β \left(\left(\frac{∂}{∂x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{∂}{∂y}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{∂}{∂z}\right)^2\right) - α \left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right)^2 + 2 \frac{∂}{∂t} \frac{∂}{∂u}, \\
dt \frac{∂}{∂t} + du \frac{∂}{∂u} + dx \frac{∂}{∂x} + dy \frac{∂}{∂y} + dz \frac{∂}{∂z},
$$
with the 4-dimensional geometry corresponding to the case where the line element for the metric is set to 0.

The symmetry groups that preserve these invariants are the respective central extensions of the symmetry groups for the first set of invariants. The central extensions are trivial if $α ≠ 0$, else non-trivial if $α = 0$. Yet, both Carroll and Static have isomorphic central extensions.

In each case, they are 5-dimensional geometries with a metric, a dual metric, an invariant vector field and invariant one-form. For $β = 0$, the metric and dual metric are respectively given by the invariants:
$$
dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2, \hspace 1em - α \left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right)^2 + 2 \frac{∂}{∂t} \frac{∂}{∂u}. \\
$$

The 2-parameter family of the symmetry groups (that are 5, up to isomorphism, 4 for their respective central extensions) is a subfamily of the 3-parameter family that consists of the 14 (13, after taking central extensions) that were laid out by Bacry and Lévy‐Leblond in 1968 in the Journal of Mathematical Physics:

**Possible Kinematics**
https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1664490

It is possible to expand the geometric representation to a form that provides a uniform 5-dimensional geometric representation for the entire family. The infinitesimal transforms that arise from the above invariants are given by:
$$
δ = × - βt + , \hspace 1em δt = -α· + τ, \hspace 1em δu = · + ψ, \\
δ(d) = ×d - βdt, \hspace 1em δ(dt) = -α·d, \hspace 1em δ(du) = ·d, \\
δ∇ = ×∇ + α \frac{∂}{∂t} - \frac{∂}{∂u}, \hspace 1em δ\left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right) = β·∇, \hspace 1em δ\left(\frac{∂}{∂u}\right) = 0,
$$
where
$$ = (x, y, z), \hspace 1em d = (dx, dy, dz), \hspace 1em ∇ = \left(\frac{∂}{∂x}, \frac{∂}{∂y}, \frac{∂}{∂z}\right),$$
which includes the infinitesimal transforms $$ for rotations and $$ for boosts, which yield the homogeneous groups, and $$ for spatial translations, $τ$ for time translations and $ψ$ for the $u$-translations, which yield the respective inhomogeneous extensions of the homogeneous groups.

The representations for the other members of the Bacry / Lévy‐Leblond family are non-linear.

Comment: A fantastic answer +1 thank you!

Comment: From https://studenttheses.uu.nl/handle/20.500.12932/39595 - "*The Carrollian limit can be obtained by starting from a relativistic system and collapsing the lightcone. This can be contrasted with the Galilean limit, which can be seen as opening up the lightcone.*" - This describes my cases 3 and 4. Is there a similar intuitive way to visualize your "another" case of $(α,β) = (0,0)$?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've given that some thought. There is quite a bit published on the "Static Group" but I'm not well-read on it. In effect, you have a 0/0 limit for c, so it's going to 0 and to ∞! If you do a dimensional analysis of the Bacry / Lévy‐Leblond family, you'll find that speed has to be treated as an independent dimension from length and time. The β coefficient is the conversion, its dimensions are length/(speed×time). So, going β → 0 forces you use α, its dimensions are time/(speed×length). Then speed = time/length. But, if α → 0, too {length,time,speed} all remain independent.

Comment: One thing I just noticed: if you look at the geometric representation, the boost transform is trivial on the space-time coordinates for the Static Group. So, all space/time slopes on a space-time diagram will be absolute, not just the horizontal ones (as for the Galilean group) or vertical ones (as for the Carroll group). Instead, there's only non-trivial action for the boost in the 5-D rep, and that's for the central extension. It matches the 5-D rep for the Carroll group, if apply it to the "proper time" s = t + α u in place of time t. In effect, both groups have the same central extension.