# Spacetime topology around a hollow shell

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

Consider a hypothetical thin massive shell located at its Schwarzschild radius (See: [Schwarzschild Metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric)). For the purpose of this question, please consider the shell is static and is not collapsing (whether or not this is physical is out of scope). The exterior spacetime is Schwarzschild implying the $\Bbb R^4$ topology.

Spacetime inside is time dilated flat (see: [On a common misunderstanding of the Birkhoff theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4428)). Due to the infinite time dilation at the horizon, time inside the shell is also infinitely dilated, so the temporal component of the metric is zero and the metric is Euclidean:

$$ ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 $$

This implies the $\Bbb R^3$ topology in the interior.

What is the topology of this global spacetime? Can it be defined? Thank you!

Comment: By "topology" do you mean the topology induced by the underlying topology of Schwarzschild spacetime? If so, it shouldn't depend on the metric at all. Of course, this is not the same as the topology of the metric (since pseudo/sub-Riemannian metrics don't induce a well defined topology iirc).

Comment: @Kajelad Please pardon my ignorance, as this is a new field for me :) but "induced" on what? And what is the difference between the topology of the manifold equipped with a metric and the topology of the metric? The topology of the Schwarzschild spacetime is $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb S^2$ according to this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5790 - which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$ with the line  $r=0$ removed: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521853/  - but in this question this line is not removed. The spacetime outside the horizon is Schwarzschild, inside - Euclidean. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Kajelad Also, strictly speaking, the metric inside may not be exactly Euclidean, but rather dual to Galilean, as described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310040/ - So split into separate temporal and spatial metrics like Galilean, which is described in the second part of the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588492/ - If any of this makes any difference :)

Comment: By "induced" I mean the subspace topology, since the "shell" is an embedded submanifold. Just looking at things as manifolds, Schwatzschild spacetime is indeed just $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2\cong\mathbb{R}^4\setminus\mathbb{R}^1$, so the shell is just $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Kajelad Oh, I see where my error is!!! Sorry about it :) Thanks for pointing this out to me, I will edit the question shortly. The question is not on the topology of the shell itself, but on the topology of the spacetime "curved" by this massive shell. You can just ignore the shell altogether. The question is, what is the topology of the global spacetime with the Schwarzschild metric at $r>r_s$ and the Euclidean (or dual to Galilean) metric at $r\le r_s$?

Comment: In that case it would just be $\mathbb{R}^4$ with a "tube" removed, which is the homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4\setminus\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Kajelad I assume you mean the $r=r_s$ hypertube (the hypersurface of a spherinder)? If so, I wonder why it is removed. My previous comment states $r\le r_s$, so the tube is included, is it not? Also, in the Schwarzschild spacetime, they only remove the $r=0$ line, but not the tube. Why? (There it is not included inside or outside, I think...) With these clarifications, can you possibly post an answer? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: The previous comment was referring to the "outside of the surface" part. The inside would depend on how you deal with the singularity at the center.

Comment: @Kajelad There is no singularity at the center. The spacetime inside is Euclidean everywhere, as long as $r\le r_s$, as stated. This ensures the required continuity of the temporal metric (it becomes zero at $r=r_s$ and stays zero everywhere inside. The spatial metric does not need to be continuous (due to the presence of the shell) and is flat inside per the Birkhoff's theorem (the GR equivalent of the Newton's shell theorem - no gravity inside a spherical shell). The flat spatial part is Euclidean and the zero temporal part makes the 4D metric degenerate and only 3D (or dual, as mentioned).